# Placing checkboxes inside of text input fields

Tags: forms, checkboxes

Okay so i am currently working on an intern application.
One of the tasks is to create a new entry for a specific contact person.

After entering all the information, the user has to decide if the entered data (Phone Number, Mobile, Fax) will be visible online on the website (people can look up contact persons on the website)

[image: My current solution (just a rough mockup)]

Since the entered data wont be really long i thought about putting a checkbox in each of those fields but im not really sure if there is a better solution.

I don't want to put the checkbox below each field since this wastes a lot of vertical real estate.

Whats your opinion?

Comment: I think it can work.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just shorten the text field and put the check box and label outside of it to the right where you have it now?

Comment: @JoelGarfield no there is no reason, i will try this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the checkboxes to the right of the form fields.

Another approach is to split it up into 2 steps. Step 1 is filling out the form and submitting the data. On step 2, show the previously entered data as static text (like a confirmation step in online shopping) and add a checkbox in front of each row. This then allows the user to decide what should be displayed and what hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your input, placing them next to the form is a valid option, i will try this out.

The thing is that the people who work with the application work with it the whole day, they repeat those processes often and therefore speed is important. Since this form is step 2 of 4 total steps (all pages have data input fields) i don't really want to make the process even longer by having an additional step for those option.

Comment: That is a good reason to keep it 1 step. Just be aware that people tend to miss fields in multi-column forms (google LukeW on form design, great resource). Also think about defaults, maybe name and email should be ticked by default but mobile not, potentially make it a setting. That improves the workflow.